# How to select object in muti level array

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am attempting to get just the smiling array under tags then attributes. I have tried both to search and simply select. Every attempt results in an undefined variable. If you could explain how to select the smiling array that would be excellent!

```
   {
        "status": "success",
        "photos": [{
            "url": "http://tinyurl.com/673cksr",
            "pid": "F@019cbdb135cff0880096136c4a0b9bad_3547b9aba738e",
            "width": 375,
            "height": 406,
            "tags": [{
                "uids": [],
                "label": null,
                "confirmed": false,
                "manual": false,
                "width": 30.67,
                "height": 28.33,
                "yaw": -16,
                "roll": -1,
                "pitch": 0,
                "attributes": {
                    "face": {
                        "value": "true",
                        "confidence": 84
                    },
                    "smiling": {
                        "value": "false",
                        "confidence": 46
                    }
                },
                "points": null,
                "similarities": null,
                "tid": "TEMP_F@019cbdb135cff0880096136c00d500a7_3547b9aba738e_56.80_41.13_0_1",
                "recognizable": true,
                "center": {
                    "x": 56.8,
                    "y": 41.13
                },
                "eye_left": {
                    "x": 66.67,
                    "y": 35.71,
                    "confidence": 51,
                    "id": 449
                },
                "eye_right": {
                    "x": 50.67,
                    "y": 35.47,
                    "confidence": 57,
                    "id": 450
                },
                "mouth_center": {
                    "x": 60.8,
                    "y": 51.23,
                    "confidence": 53,
                    "id": 615
                },
                "nose": {
                    "x": 62.4,
                    "y": 42.61,
                    "confidence": 54,
                    "id": 403
                }
            }]
        }],
        "usage": {
            "used": 21,
            "remaining": 79,
            "limit": 100,
            "reset_time": 1390111833,
            "reset_time_text": "Sun, 19 January 2014 06:10:33 +0000"
        },
        "operation_id": "edc2f994cd8c4f45b3bc5632fdb27824"
    }
```

Comment: `smiling` is an object not an Array object.

Comment: my mistake, edited the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(json).photos[0].tags[0].attributes.smiling
```

Answer (score 2):

This particular code, will aggregate all the `smiling` attribute from the given object and return that as an Array.

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function will get `smiling` attribute from each and every tag
- [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) function will flatten all the attributes and returns a single array per photo.
- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function will gather all the attributes all the photos and accumulate the result in `result` and that will be returned at the end.

---

```
var result = data.photos.reduce(function(result, currentPhoto) {
    return result.concat(currentPhoto.tags.map(function(currentTag) {
        return currentTag.attributes.smiling;
    }));
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ { value: 'false', confidence: 46 } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
obj.photos[0].tags[0].attributes.smiling
```

The best way would be to loop through the tags, instead of hardcoding 0 in there

```js
obj.photos.forEach(function(photo){
  photo.tags.forEach(function(tag){ 
    tag.attributes.smiling; // here it is
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky since your JSON object is a mixture of objects and arrays, but here's how you would get to the "smiling" object (it's an object since there's no associative arrays in JavaScript):

```
var smiling_object = obj["photos"][0]["tags"][0]["attributes"]["smiling"];
```

Then you if you want to do something with it:

```
var some_var = smiling_object["value"];
var some_other_var = smiling_object["confidence"];

alert("The combined string is " + some_var + " and " + some_other_var);
```